# unable to scrape non-english fonts - selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, encoding

I am new to selenium and I am trying few sites for testing purposes.
Came across a scenario where the tamil and hindi fonts are scrapped as "??????"

I tried to open the output via notepad++, sublimetext and excel but still displays as "??????"

```
Xpath tried - //h1//following::p[@id='topDescription']

Test URLs
"https://www.hooq.tv/catalog/7a6d593d-e8f3-47b6-92ae-469b8e08178e?__sr=feed"
"https://www.hooq.tv/catalog/d023630f-882b-4df4-8cb5-857ebfff20b4?__sr=feed"
```

code

```
d.get("https://www.hooq.tv/catalog/7a6d593d-e8f3-47b6-92ae-469b8e08178e?__sr=feed");
d.findElement(By.xpath("//h1//following::p[@id='topDescription']")).getText();
```

Is this something about encoding issue ?

Comment: It would be better if the scrape data is directly saved to those file formats which support that sort of content.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you can get the raw text properly before saving it into an external file.

I tested the .getText() in java for your element and it is returning the String as-is.

[image]
Next, you need to make sure that during file writing, the charset encoding is UTF-8.

Here's a sample using `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`:

```
FileUtils.write(new File("C:/temp/test.txt"), str, "UTF-8");
FileUtils.write(new File("C:/temp/test.csv"), str, "UTF-8");
```

[image]

Hope it helps.